# how to change the order for the java annotation?

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations

```
public @interface TestAnnotation{

    int id();
    String title(); 

}
```

I have one java annotation as listed above. When I use the auto generated code to use it in eclipse, It will list the *id=...* before *title=*, So can I change the order for auto generated code in eclipse?

Of cause, I can change it by changing the id's first letter to a letter behind the 't', but how to do it with other better method?

Comment: Why do you care?

Comment: because I want give the user better experience that there is no need to change the order by manuals.

Comment: Have you tried just reversing their order in the interface?

Comment: tried,no workable, it still keep the sequence of letter